# What happens when I use the same variable name in a function called via ajax, that i have previously defined?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme and have a page template setup that calls a template part. 
This template part runs a query to load some post types. 
The query arguments are passed from the main template when the page first loads.
when a button is pressed  an ajax function is called that sets the arguments again ( using the same variable name) and re runs the template part.

main template file:

```
get_header();

$venue_search_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_venue', //set the arguments for the search query here.
    'post_status' => 'publish',   
);

?>
<div id ="venue-filter-form">
    <form id="venue-search" action="venue-search.php" method="post">
      //search form here
    </form>
</div>
<?php 
    include(locate_template('/template-parts/template-venue-part-1.php')); // include the post content ( this includes the search query)
get_footer();
?>
```

The above calls the following template part file which contains a query to search all of the posts types and display them in a div where the class = the category name.

```
$query = new WP_Query($venue_search_args);
while ($query->have_posts()) {  ?> 
   <div class=" venue <?php      
       $formatted_cats = format_category_output(get_the_taxonomies(get_the_ID())); //return an array of formatted categories the value sent to the function is an array of unformatted categories for the post 
    if (is_array($formatted_cats)){
        $i=0;
        $len = count($formatted_cats);
            foreach ($formatted_cats as $key ) {
                if ($i == $len-1){
                    echo $key ;
                }
                else {
                echo $key;
                echo ' ';
                    }
                $i++;
            }
        }
else { echo 'uncategorised'; }
 ?>">
```

Below is my current unfinished ajax call im using to test: This removes everything from the div containing all of my posts, leaving me with a blank page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#venue-search").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery("#venues-to-show").empty(); // stop form submit
      //get the value in the drop down
        var category = jQuery("#venue-search-category").val();
        var data = {
            action: 'venue_search',
            category: category 
        };
      jQuery.post(venue_searchAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
             //alert('got this from the server: ' + response) ;

    });
});
  });
```

The ajax request is sent to a file containing the following function. The function called attempts to set some new query arguments and the call the same template part as before. eventually i will parse the result back to re form the page only displaying the posts with the searched category.

```
function venue_search() {
            $category = $_POST['category'];
            $venue_search_args  = array(
                        'post_type' => 'tribe_venue',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => $category
                            ),
                    ));
            get_template_part( '/template-parts/template-venue-part-1'); 
            die();
    }
```

What im wondering is how the variable $venue_search_args will work? should i be making this a global/session instead so im accessing/changing the value of the same one?

I don't really understand how it will behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_template_part()` acts as a php `require()`, it means this line is actually replaced by the code found inside the imported file. So, if you create a variable before the import, you can use just as it is in the file you want to import. If you import inside a function, variables created inside your imported code will be local, the code is just inserted where the import is made.

To make `$venue_search_args` global to be able to modify it from the outside is possible, of course, the only mandatory thing is that the variable is defined where the imported code is placed.

If you don't need to modify it from the outside, but want only to be able to modify these parameters for each call, you can add a parameter to your `data`, and you can retreive it as a `POST` value inside `venue_search`, the same way it is done with `category`. You can then change this variable for each search without making it global:

```
var data = {
    action: 'venue_search',
    category: category,
    posttype: 'tribe_venue' //example with post type
};
```

then:

```
function venue_search() {
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $posttype = $_POST['posttype']; //get the value that changes $venue_search_args
    $venue_search_args  = array(
        'post_type' => $posttype,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $category
            ),
        ));
    get_template_part( '/template-parts/template-venue-part-1'); 
    die();
}
```

Hope that this is what you wanted, if not, just comment, i'll help :)